# How to set spark-job-server config?

Tags: apache-spark, bigdata, spark-jobserver

I am running spark-job-server 0.5.3 from ooyala. I have followed their official documents and it works fine when it is started by sbt using reStart command. But i can't

1. make it work using server_start.sh script.
2. unable to run it on a standalone cluster. its working on local[*] master bydefault now there are no clear doc about how to run the job-server on standalone cluster.

any solution or link to any blog or proper docs is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this still a problem for you? I have worked on a chef cookbook that should set it up with upstart scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Documentation for the main spark job server project here: [github.com/spark-jobserver](https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver#deployment)

- Copy config/local.sh.template to .sh and edit as
  appropriate. NOTE: be sure to set SPARK_VERSION if you need to
  compile against a different version, ie. 1.4.1 for job server 0.5.2
- Copy config/shiro.ini.template to shiro.ini and edit as appropriate.
  NOTE: only required when authentication = on
- Copy config/local.conf.template to .conf and edit as
  appropriate. bin/server_deploy.sh  -- this packages the
  job server along with config files and pushes it to the remotes you
  have configured in .sh
- On the remote server, start it in the deployed directory with
  server_start.sh and stop it with server_stop.sh
- The server_start.sh script uses spark-submit under the hood and may
  be passed any of the standard extra arguments from spark-submit.

NOTE: by default the assembly jar from job-server-extras, which includes support for SQLContext and HiveContext, is used. If you face issues with all the extra dependencies, consider modifying the install scripts to invoke sbt job-server/assembly instead, which doesn't include the extra dependencies.

Comment: Thanks @Gillespie, i've moved the local.conf and local.sh in bin/ because it tries to find every file in bin/. it actually passing a jar from bin to spark-submit in the server_start.sh script, Now i edited the script to use the jar from job-server/ . when i run the server_start.sh now it asks for InstrumentedActor which is in another project so i edited the script further more and added --jars option from spark-submit and passed the akka-app jar. then the server_start.sh script throws java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: spray/routing/HttpService.
Now please help me to understand what am i missing.